# Regular Expression in Tcl to parse a line

Tags: tcl

i need a regular expression to separate left and right part of this pattern . . . . . :
for e.g.

```
Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : alumnus.co.in
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

and store them into two variable.
i have written this regular expression

```
regexp {([[a-z]*[0-9]*.*[0-9]*[a-z]*]*" "):([[a-z]*[0-9]*.*[0-9]*[a-z]*]*)} 6*rag5hu. . :4ku5-1a543m match a b
```

but it is not working.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
set text {Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : alumnus.co.in
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes}

foreach line [split $text \n] {
    if {[regexp {^(.+?)(?: \.)+ : (.+)$} $line -> name value]} {
        puts "$name => $value"
    }
}
```

outputs

```
Media State => Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  => alumnus.co.in
   Description => Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. => 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. => No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled => Yes
```

This uses a non-greedy quantifier (`+?`), and that make *every* quantifier in the regex non-greedy. You then require the anchors so that the bits you want to capture contain all the text you need.

Comment: It's probably worth doing a `string trim $name " ."` to get rid of the irrelevant bits.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing the definition of `text`:

```
package require textutil

foreach line [split $text \n] {
    lassign [::textutil::splitx [string trim $line] {\s*(?:\. )+:\s*}] a b
    puts "a: $a\nb: $b"
}
```

Giving the output

```
a: Media State
b: Media disconnected
a: Connection-specific DNS Suffix
b: alumnus.co.in
a: Description
b: Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
a: Physical Address
b: 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
a: DHCP Enabled
b: No
a: Autoconfiguration Enabled
b: Yes
```

Documentation:
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[lassign](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lassign.htm),
[package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[textutil (package)](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil.html)